# How to display data of char to DrawText() in raylib? I am stuck

Tags: c, raylib

I am making simple game of guessing a verse in the Bible. What makes me confuse is when using `DrawText()`. It says it should string, containing %s in the inside, but my data is `char`, so it uses `%c`, instead of `%s`. So, I try to use while loop. But it seems not working. I am stuck doing it a whole day.
Any ideas? Many thanks. I am newbie trying to make a game.

What I am trying to do is like this:

```c
BeginDrawing();


                        DrawText(TextFormat("    %d:%d ", surahChoice, ayatChoice), 242, 260, 20, MAROON);
                        //name of surah:
                        while(*ptrTheSurah != '\n')
                        {
                                DrawText(TextFormat("             %c", theSurahString), 242, 260, 20, MAROON);
                              DrawText(" ",242,260,20,MAROON);
                              ptrTheSurah++;
                        }

                EndDrawing();
```

Comment: if using just console programming, that's works! Imagine DrawText() is replaced by printf()..

Answer (score 0):

Your data is most likely array of `char`, so using `%s` would be the correct choice.

I assume that `theSurahString` is `const char *`, so a pointer. That means that by using `%c` you are telling `TextFormat()` to convert that pointer to integer and then to slim it down to 8 bits and print and handle that as character code.